# GitHub configuration terminal says "no such file or directory"

Tags: macos, git, github

I'm following the [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) to configure GitHub but my mac terminal says that I have no such file or directory.

```
iMac-di-:~ user$ git credential-osxkeychain
Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
iMac-di-:~ user$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain  "$(dirname $(which git))/git-credential-osxkeychain"
mv: rename git-credential-osxkeychain to /usr/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory
```

In fact `which git`give me `/usr/bin/git` but it seems that even if I change the path the problem is still there. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message isn't talking about the destination path; it's talking about the source path.

- In command 1, you're telling `git` to look for a file named `git-credential-osxkeychain` in all `$PATH` directories, plus git's private directory where it keeps the default subcommands. (You can use `which` to see where the file actually is.)
- In command 2, you're telling `mv` to look for a file named `git-credential-osxkeychain` in the current directory (your home directory according to shell prompt).

Notice how these are not the same location.

---

Also notice that the second command is not necessary at all, because the first one already works fine – `git` correctly finds the `git-credential-osxkeychain` helper that was installed earlier. This means that you **do not need to install it manually again.** It's already working.